# Can't run php artisan Error "service php is not running container #1" using docker

Tags: php, docker

After success build container on docker, try running with docker-compose up -d, until here is okay. But try to run artisan CLI, I have an error with message `Service "php" is not running container #1`. This project using lumen framework. Before I'm using Windows for OS

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: appbilling-service
    container_name: appbilling-api
    volumes:
      - app-data:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    links:
      - db

  server:
    image: nginx:1.23-alpine
    container_name: appbilling-server
    ports:
      - 8100:80
    volumes:
      - app-data:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - app

  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mydb
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - 33061:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: appbilling_test
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./docker/mysql/mysql.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

volumes:
  db-data:
  app-data:
```

and this is my dockerfile

```
FROM composer:2 as vendor

COPY ./database ./database
COPY ./tests ./tests

COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock

RUN composer install \
    --ignore-platform-reqs \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --prefer-dist


FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

COPY . /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . .
COPY --from=vendor /app/vendor ./vendor/
COPY ./docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    oniguruma-dev \
    mysql-client \
    libxml2-dev \
    # If you have enabled gd plugin
    # libpng-dev \
    # libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    # freetype-dev \
    git \
    zip \
    unzip \
    curl

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    bcmath \
    mbstring \
    pdo \
    pdo_mysql \
    tokenizer \
    xml

# If you need to work with image manipulation.
# RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
# RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN adduser www-data www-data

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data .

USER www-data

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

I'm try to run lumen sevrice with port 8100 is run normally